# Azure devops not running MS test unit tests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-devops, mstest

Ran into a strange issue with Azure Dev ops. I am trying to build my project in Azure Dev ops.

.Net Project structure looks like this in VS:

```
Solution
--src
--Test
----Test Proj. 1
----Test Proj. 2
```

And my azure-pipeline.yml looks like this:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  BuildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '3.1.x'
    includePreviewVersions: true
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: 'nuget.config'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: 'Project.sln'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    msbuildArchitecture: x64
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: Test
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*.UnitTest.dll
      !**\obj\**
    vsTestVersion: latest
    runSettingsFile: test\test.runsettings
    codeCoverageEnabled: true
    platform: $(BuildPlatform)
    configuration: $(BuildConfiguration)
    diagnosticsEnabled: true
    runInParallel: true
```

It is not able to find any test cases to run, and completes the step without running any test.

Is there something that I am missing here? or do I have to specify something else in the config?

My Test project.csproj file contains this:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CsvHelper" Version="18.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.7.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="1.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Azure devops not running MS test unit tests

According to your settings for Test files is:

```
  **\*.UnitTest.dll
  !**\obj\**
```

You should make sure that **the name of your test project ends with `.UnitTest`**, like `Test.UnitTest`, otherwise, the generate dll file should not be `*.UnitTest.dll`.

To resolve this issue, you could use `test` as a matching keyword(Make sure your test project name contains the `test` keyword):

```
**\*test*.dll
!**\*TestAdapter.dll
!**\obj\**
```

If above not help you, please try to share your test project name and the log of your test task.

Comment: Thanks Leo, my test projects name has "Tests" in the end, so it was getting skipped

Answer (score 3):

For those seeing this thread whose problem is not due to the path being incorect:  Check you have an appropriate test adapter for the framework you're using.  In the above case it was `MSTest` so `MSTest.TestAdapter` nuget package would need to be installed in each test project